# to export the output generated in python to excel file

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Given below is some part of data, I want to export the data from output box in Jupyter Notebook to the excel file. The data is quite huge like 10k lines.

17:38:00
17:38:01
17:38:02
17:38:03
17:38:04
.
.
.
Following is my code:-

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
load_var=pd.read_csv(r'path')

# Select the dataframe
col_var=load_var['End Seconds']

# Converting the dataframe to array

a=col_var.values.tolist()


# define the function for time conversion
def convert(seconds): 
seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600) 
hour = seconds // 3600
seconds %= 3600
minutes = seconds // 60
seconds %= 60

return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds) 


for n in a:
print(convert(n))
```

1)Please suggest the addition to be made in the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply your function to the series that you want to modify like this:

```
load_var = pd.read_csv(r'path')    
load_var['End Seconds'] = load_var['End Seconds'].apply(convert)
```

Now you have the converted data in memory which can be saved to Excel using `df.to_excel()` as Fahmi mentioned.

Comment: SunilG thank you so much it precisely worked out. It was a flawless and easy method, appreciate your quick response to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.to_excel()` for exporting to excel file

```
df.to_excel(r'Path to store the exported excel file\File Name.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: But the output is in the output window and not assigned to any variable.